# how to propagate git commit details from one job to another in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to propagate git commit details in a pipeline from a parent job to child jobs that all share the same git clone?

So basically one git clone is triggered from a master job and the master job create mini jenkins pipeline jobs (build test etc.. with job DSL plugin). The master shows changes to git. The commits show like this.

[image]

The problem is the child jobs do not inherit this commit information. They also do not, and cannot do a git pull themselves, because they would advance the git checkout. But perhaps they can inspect git checkout details.

Is it possible to pass that info down to the child jobs from the master job or from git itself ?

Comment: what kind of details?

Comment: The usual details of commits. the image above shows 2 commits.  the child jobs show no commits.  commit details always show what files where changed and by whom.

Comment: you mean the change log from last build, right? basically the git plugin in jenkins will consider the last build commit hash to generate the change log so the nested jobs will not have this information... so you must to read it from git log somehow and send it to the nested jobs via build params

Comment: Yep that's what I'm asking and being searching for. Any ideas on how to do it ?